# How do you yank a part of a line in vi?

Tags: vi

I've spent quite a bit of time searching for an answer, but I can only find answers for **vim**, which suggest using visual mode or registers. Neither of these seem like options for vi (version SVR4.0, Solaris 2.5.0). I know about `D`, `yy`, `dd`, which yank or delete the entire line or up to the end up the line.

I'm now wondering if it's even possible to yank/delete a part of a line: say, the part within the brackets in:
I want to co[py this par]t of the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the movement commands work with `yank`, like `h, j, k, l` for left, down, up, right. So if the cursor is on the first `p` in

```
I want to co[py this par]t of the line.
```

`y11l` (yank eleven ell) gives

```
py this par
```

`y3w` gives you the next 3 words, meaning if the closing `]` is not there it'll include the final `t`.

If your cursor is on the `[` (assuming that's actually part of the string), `y%` (move to matching bracket) gives:

```
[py this par]
```

Comment: Thanks. What if those brackets aren't actually a part of that line (I only meant for them to visually demarcate the intended yank region)? In a longer, more complex span of text (possibly spanning multiple lines), having to count the number of words or number of characters right/down seems really impractical, or at least really inconvenient. Is this just a limitation of vi that I'd have to get used to?

Comment: I figured the brackets weren't really there, but I thought I'd give the option. I think you're stuck with counting characters, words or lines unless the answer from @dave works for you (perhaps with a temporary tag character added to the beginning or end of the desired substring?).

Comment: By the way, I haven't used Solaris in a while, but will the window manager handle the clipboard for you? Highlight the string with the mouse and paste with the middle button?

Answer (score 0):

You can do

`y` `f` `character`

Which will `[y]ank` until it `[f]inds` whatever `character`.

In your example. you could

```
f p y f r
```

Find p - yank until you find r

For your example

> I want to co[py this part of t]he line

I usually will do

`f` `p` - find p

`y` - enter "yank mode"

`/he line` - up until you find the phrase "he line"

`Enter`

Where "he line" is just whatever text comes after the character, and I type until I know it's enough to select it and not something else.

Comment: Thanks! I see how it works for the example above, but what if the text I am yanking contains multiple occurences of the final character? Example: I want to co[py this part of t]he line.

Comment: You can use a count with your `f` command:  `y` `3f` `t` will yank until the third `t`.  The `t` command moves to the character before the one specified, so `y` `2f` `h` would also work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the marker feature.

For the line: “I want to co[py this par]t of the line.“,
First move the cursor past the ‘r’ character using any means you want.  Then mark it with ‘m1’.  Next, move the cursor after the ‘o’ character.  To select the text, use command “y`1”.  This yanks the text between the current cursor at ‘o’ to the cursor position at marker 1.  You can then move to another cursor position and copy the text with the put ‘p’ command.